# List Comprehension to old fashioned for loop

Tags: python, loops, dataframe, list-comprehension

[image: Main DF]

I am trying to understand better the list comprehension way of writing for loops but I still am confused with the semantic error I am getting!

This one is the list comprehension!

```
df["year"] = [int(s.split("-")[1]) for i in df["Month"]]
df["month"] = [str(s.split("-")[0]) for i in df["Month"]]
```

THis is correct what I am getting! Each of the years from 90s to 2020! I am showing 15 only!

[image: whatiwant]

Now I am trying to write the same thing but in an old fashioned for loop way!

```
for i in df['Month']:
    df['year'] = int((i.split("-")[1]))
```

[image: whatiget]

As you can see I am getting repeated values instead of getting all the years from start to the beginning as in the first image!

Comment: You appear to be setting `df['month']` in your `for` loop, but are then printing out `df["year"]`. Is that the issue?

Comment: @Sam I am trying to create a new column called "year" which is taking the year from the column "Month"! and also "month" as a new column which is taking the month from the "Month" column! Thats why I am splitting with the  dash!

Comment: Can you show your input dataframe?

Comment: I just edited the thing you mentioned above you were right, and yes ill show you the dataframe now!

Comment: @Sam I added the main DF!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is that you are setting one value: `df['year'] = int((i.split("-")[0]))` on each loop through. In your list comprehension you are setting `df["year"]` and `df["month"]` to lists, rather than a single value. You need to either add another index to what you are setting in your dataframe, or build a list that you use to set that column in the `df`. And as was said above, isn't year the 2nd value in the split `[1]` instead of `[0]` ? Also, using `i` as your element is bad practice, as `i` is usually assumed to be an index, and here it is the whole cell `AUG-90`.

If you really want a for-loop, you can use this:

```
df['Month'] = [
    'Apr-90',
    'May-90',
    'Jun-90',
    'Jul-90',
    'Aug-90',
    'Jan-91',
    'Feb-91',
]
years = []
for i in df['Month']:
    years.append(int((i.split("-")[1])))
df['year'] = years
>>> print(df)
Month  year
0  Apr-90    90
1  May-90    90
2  Jun-90    90
3  Jul-90    90
4  Aug-90    90
5  Jan-91    91
6  Feb-91    91
```

Comment: it is [1] I just edited it was a typo in here, in my actual code I have it [1]

Comment: ok, but the main issue is setting the `year` column to a single value each time through the loop!

Comment: I know that I am actually not iterating through the year[1], can you please demonstrate me on how to, I cannot seem to grasp it at the moment! I am literally just iterating through the same last value of the column apparently which is 2020(20)!

Comment: Do you need something like `df['year'][i] = int((i.split("-")[1]))` ? Or some other dataframe-specific way to set the `i'th` value in the `year` column on the `i'th` iteration.

Comment: The dataframe has 360 items, more specifically it has all the months of the year starting from 1990 april to 2020 april, so 30*12 =360, so I need to iterate through all the years starting from the april 1990 till the end 2020 april, more like the 2nd image uploaded above under list comprehension code, thats what I am looking forward to get!

Comment: As I said, you are setting the `'year'` column to a single value, over and over. So the whole column has the last value you set, `20`, in all locations. That's what `df['year'] = 20` does. First you are setting the entire column to `90`, then `91`, then finally `20`, which is the last value. You need to set individual cells in that column, or build a list to set that column to.

Comment: I updated my answer, with a `for` loop that generates a list, that is used to set the `year` column.

Comment: Thank you so much man, appreciate it, now I get how dumb my mistake was lol sorry for taking this much of your time!

Comment: I haven't done programming in quite some time, trying to get back into it !!!!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a code typo in the index after the split:

```
for i in df['Month']:
    df['year'] = int((i.split("-")[1]))
```

Comment: I was running this code actually it was a typo here in the page! I am still having the same issue as described above!